# How to insert word between string in array?

Tags: javascript

I have such a data structure:

```
const array = ["item", "item1", "item2", "item4"]
```

items can be different number. I need to convert this data into
"item" OR "item1" OR "item2" OR "item4" 
I used lodash join() but it gives me string "item OR item1 OR item2 OR item4"
and this is not what I need. How can I receive such a structure `"item" OR "item1" OR "item2" OR "item4` from an array?

Comment: So you want a result to be a single string which contains those double quotes and such?

Comment: please add a practical example of the wanted output.

Comment: @NinaScholz "item" OR "item1" OR "item2" OR "item4 is this doesn't example?

Comment: @NinaScholz check ponury-kostek answer, it is what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `join()` and wrap result with extra `"`

```js
const array = ["item", "item1", "item2", "item4"]
console.log('"' + array.join('" OR "') + '"')
```

Answer (score 2):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the elements to return them as quoted strings (here using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)), *then* [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them:

```js
const array = ["item", "item1", "item2", "item4"];
const str = array.map(el => `"${el}"`).join(' OR ');
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use stringify the items and join with `' OR '`.

```js
const
    array = ["item", "item1", "item2", "item4"],
    string = array.map(o => JSON.stringify(o)).join(' OR ');

console.log(string);
```